# Open *.txt with file selector from vb console application

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, console-application

I need to use a console application. I would like a file selector to open so the user can select any .txt file. I have looked at OpenFileDialog but as far as I can see that only works for form applications.

This kind of window is what I was looking for:

[image: this sort of thing]

Comment: You really shouldn't be using UI components in Console applications. The plumbing is not built in the Console framework for User Interface interaction.

Comment: @Shiva although I agree, but this can be done easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said, you should not be using Windows-UI in Console Apps, that said, here's how you do it for your requirement.

I wrote it on my local machine and it works.

Create a new VB.Net Console Project, and Reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and paste this entire code in the `module1.vb`
(P.S. I update it to include [@Codexer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797425/codexer)'s recommendation, and also included the error message in the exception handler.)

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Module1

    <STAThread()> _
    Sub Main()
        Dim OpenFileDlg as new OpenFileDialog

            OpenFileDlg.FileName = "" ' Default file name
            OpenFileDlg.DefaultExt = ".txt" ' Default file extension
            OpenFileDlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.TXT"
            OpenFileDlg.Multiselect = True
            OpenFileDlg.RestoreDirectory = True
            ' Show open file dialog box
            Dim result? As Boolean = OpenFileDlg.ShowDialog()

            ' Process open file dialog box results
    for each path in OpenFileDlg.Filenames
      Try
                             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error loading the file" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
            If result = True Then
                ' Open document
            Else
                  Exit Sub
            End If
    next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Here's the output.

[image]

Comment: You need to `Add Reference` not just the `Import` statement. Also make sure to add the attribute **`<STAThread()>`** as if not used it can cause possible deadlocks as this would need to a pump message. This is very important specifically for the `COM` threading model in which the `OpenFileDialog` uses.

Comment: @Codexer Thank you for your recommendation on the `<STAThread()>`. I've updated my answer and also improved the error handling.